# C# Revit API, how to create a simple wall using ExternalCommand?

Tags: revit-api

I just wanted to learn Revit API and create a simple wall using ExternalCommand. But I cannot figure it out...
I think my problem is here:

`var symbolId = document.GetDefaultFamilyTypeId(new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls));`

When I debug it `symbolId` always -1.

Can you help me what is wrong with this code snippet?

```
public Autodesk.Revit.UI.Result Execute(
    Autodesk.Revit.UI.ExternalCommandData command_data,
    ref string message,
    Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
{
    var document = command_data.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    var level_id = new ElementId(1526);
    // create line
    XYZ point_a = new XYZ(-10, 0, 0);
    XYZ point_b = new XYZ(10, 10, 10);
    Line line = Line.CreateBound(point_a, point_b);

    using (var transaction = new Transaction(doc))
    {
        transaction.Start("create walls");

        Wall wall = Wall.Create(doc, line, level_id, false);
        var position = new XYZ(0, 0, 0);
        var symbolId = document.GetDefaultFamilyTypeId(new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls));
        if (symbolId == ElementId.InvalidElementId) {
            transaction.RollBack();
            return Result.Failed;
        }

        var symbol = document.GetElement(symbolId) as FamilySymbol;
        var level = (Level)document.GetElement(wall.LevelId);
        document.Create.NewFamilyInstance(position, symbol, wall, level, StructuralType.NonStructural);

        transaction.Commit();
    }

    return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work through the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) and all will be explained. That will save you and others many further questions and answers.

To address this specific question anyway, `GetDefaultFamilyTypeId` presumably does not do what you expect it to for wall elements. In the [`GetDefaultFamilyTypeId` method API documentation](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/34d20683-dfea-b1f8-14cf-750611b218ed.htm), it is used for structural columns, a standard loadable family hosted by individual RFA files. Walls are built-in system families and behave differently. Maybe `GetDefaultFamilyTypeId` only works for non-system families.

To retrieve an arbitrary (not default) wall type, use a filtered element collector to retrieve all `WallType` elements and pick the first one you find.

Here is a code snippet that picks the first one with a specific name, from [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discussion on [Creating Face Wall and Mass Floor](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/12/creating-face-wall-and-mass-floor.html)
:

```
WallType wType = new FilteredElementCollector( doc )
  .OfClass( typeof( WallType ) )
  .Cast<WallType>().FirstOrDefault( q
    => q.Name == "Generic - 6\" Masonry" );
```

Comment: I solved the problem and created many different types of walls already after read [Revit Api Developers Guide](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Revit-API/Revit_API_Developers_Guide.html). But your getting started link is also helpful information for newbies. So I accept the answer.